# Manage some field data stored in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of grain sizes collected in the field. But not everything is a measurable rock, sometimes I end up with things like debris (D) or bedrock (B):

[image]

I am trying to calculate the percentage of each unmeasurable, convert sand (S) to a number (0.5), and make some of the larger numbers fit into discrete categories (220 -> 256).

Everything that I have found to deal with the str values breaks when it encounters an int, and everything that I have found to deal with int values breaks when it encounters a str.

I could use a little help here.

Working code:

```
#import the dataset to be read, full file path
dict=pd.read_excel('/media/path', sheet_name=None)

#iterate through all of the sheets of the input data, will be stored as pandas dataframes nested in a dictionary
for df in dict.values():
    #count of bedrock, is also % since there are 100 values
    B=0
    #count of debris
    D=0
    #specify numbers for sand and silt. Chosen from near the middle of Wentworth size classes.
    s={'S':0.5}
    l={'L':0.01,'C':0.01}
    for col in df:
        for item in df[col]:
            if (type(item)==str):
                if 'B' in item:
                    B+=1
                if 'D' in item:
                    D+=1
        #turn sand and silt into numbers to keep in grain size analysis
        df=df.replace(s)
        df=df.replace(l)
        #turn all of the strings to nan for calculations
        df[col]=pd.to_numeric(df[col],errors='coerce')  
        #discretize larger pebbles
        df[col]=pd.cut(df[col], bins=size_class,labels=label,right=True)
```

Comment: Hi, could you show some of your code, or at least what the expected result should look like?

Comment: This is how I want the table to look after calculating the # of occurrences of each str.

nan,2.8,45,128,45,90,180,128,nan,nan;
nan,nan,180,45,90,45,128,45,11,nan;
64,128,90,45,2.8,45,64,45,128,5.6;
nan,45,64,64,64,32,45,128,90,nan;
32,180,45,16,22.6,180,32,90,64,180;
90,32,11,32,nan,45,11,45,128,2;
2.8,360,180,180,nan,22.6,5.6,128,16,128;
16,45,2.8,22.6,16,128,90,180,5.6,nan;
16,64,32,8,90,128,90,128,nan,nan;
nan,16,180,16,1024,360,256,128,32,90;

Comment: add the related code snippet and the above data into your question by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you need to know the type of each item in the table to perform your calculations and operations on it.
This is possibleusing the function `type()` (and `.isdigit()` method for the numeric strings).

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [2,8.5,125,12,'D'],
    [145,82,63.1,'B',41.9],
    [75,54,'D',253,21],
    
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


for column in df:
    for item in df[column]:
        #check item is a string
        if (type(item) == str):
            print(item, "is a string")
            
        # check item is number (int,float,number in string)
        elif (type(item) == float) or (type(item) == int) or (str(item).isdigit()):
            print(item, "is a number")
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked wonderfully. Now I am getting stuck trying to categorize the larger values. I am trying this: elif (type(item)==float) or (type(item)==int):
                if item > 8192:
                    item=11520
                elif 8192 >= item > 5760:
                    item=8192
                elif 5760 >= item > 4096:
                    item=5760

but it does not work. Any further recommendations?

Comment: I am currently trying:

df[col]=pd.cut(df[col], bins=[0,0.01,0.5,2,2.8,4,5.6,8,11,16,22.6,32,45,64,90,128,190,256,360,512,720,1024,1440,2048,2880,4096,5760,8192,11520,np.inf],labels=False,right=True)+1

and it categorizes the values nicely, just not into the categories that I want them to be in.

Comment: I was able to get it working. Thank you for your help.